# Sorting minus number strings with AngularJS 'orderBy'

Tags: angularjs, string, integer, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am reverse ordering some number strings with the orderBy directive that can be used in conjunction with ngRepeat.

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in standings| orderBy:['-points', '-gd', 'team_name']">
      <p>{{item.gd}}
 </div>
```

So it is ordering (in order of priority) 'points', then 'gd' (goal difference), then 'team_name' (alphabetically).

The `gd` value correctly orders by descending value. The problem I have is with negative number values. In this instance, numbers are returned as strings, and the orderBy function doesn't understand `"-2"` as being less than `"-1"`, but the opposite.

How can I get ng-repeat to parse the number values into integers, particularly to solve this ordering issue with minus numbers?

I considered making a filter, e.g: `{{item.gd | *filterHere* }}`, but this wouldn't be seen by the initial ng-repeat directive, which needs to take the source value as an integer.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:**

I tried this filter, but when I call it in my ng-repeat, it returns nothing:

```
 app.filter('stringToInteger', function() {
       return function(input) {
             angular.forEach(input, function(value) {
                 parseInt(value.gd);
             })
          };
       return input;
   });
```

**In the View:**

```
<p ng-repeat="item in standings | orderBy: '-gd' | stringToInteger">GD = {{item.gd}}</p>
```

Comment: Why don't you set `standing.gd` to `int` directly in JavaScript? You can do this easily with parseInt(): http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: Thanks. I tried using this with a custom filter but it didn't work - please see my update...

Answer (score 3):

the filter should be like this.

```
app.filter('stringToInteger', function() {
   return function(input) {
         angular.forEach(input, function(value) {
            value.gd =  parseInt(value.gd);
         })
   return input;
   };
});
```

Use it like this .

```
<tr ng-repeat="team in teams | stringToInteger | orderBy:'-gd'">
```

Plunker link for more reference.

https://plnkr.co/edit/GRfMJnRdT1Gu5RXO9elA?p=preview

Comment: Thanks - but I tried this and it returned nothing. I also tried a variation (please see update), but still the ng-repeat returned nothing... Can you spot what is wrong with either syntax?

Comment: Hi, I think the plunker link I gave you is a working example. Did you try that also??

Comment: the issue with your code that you are not assigning the number converted value back , use the  code and plunker updated in the answer.

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot! My issue now is that I already have a filter to pick out a specific property in my ng-repeat, is it possible to call two filters on an ng-repeat? Current ng-repeat:  `<tr ng-repeat="item in standings | orderBy:['-points', '-gd', 'team_name'] | filter: { comp_group: 'Group A' }:true">`. Obviously I now want to call `stringToInteger` as well. What would you suggest here?

Comment: you can use multiple filter in angular. Try like this.  <tr ng-repeat="player in players | filter: { comp_group: 'Group A' } | filter:  stringToInteger">